# C#: Delegates - Java: ActionListener

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I am new with C#. I am wondering how to implement Delegates properly. So far I have programmed in Java. What I want to implement in C# would be in Java:

```
public interface CustomListener {
  void onStart(Song song);
  void onPause();
  void onStop();
}
```

How do I do this in C#? I have tried it like this:

```
public event EventHandler<Song> CustomEventHandler;
```

The problem I see is that not every method receives a song as parameter.

In advance thanks for your help.

Regards

Comment: You'd want three events - one for start, one for pause, one for stop. Or you could have one event along the lines of "StateChanged".

Comment: Can you please describe more about what you're trying to do? The interface you provided in Java is perfectly fine as it is in C#. So I think you need to describe why you want to add delegates to this interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple example you can use something the following:

```
public interface CustomListener
{
    event Action<Song> OnStart;

    event Action OnPause;

    event Action OnStop;
}
```

where `Action` and `Action<T>` are the generic delegates that come from .Net framework out of the box.